# How to One-Hot encode multiple columns at once in dataFrame using Keras.to_Categorical?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, data-science, one-hot-encoding

I want to one-hot encode multiple columns in my data frame at once using Keras to_categorical. How to do it?

`need_to_encode = ['Item_Fat_Content', 'Outlet_Location_Type', 'Outlet_Type', 'Outlet_Size', 'Item_Type_Combined', 'Outlet']`

These are the columns I need to one-hot encode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you could use this util function over every column that needs encoding of your data.

Or you use [scikit-learn's categorical encoder](https://15359-843222-gh.circle-artifacts.com/0/home/ubuntu/scikit-learn/doc/_build/html/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.CategoricalEncoder.html) on the part of the dataframe you need to encode.

Next time don't forget to include a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), this way we can help further.